# How do I add color for every pair of triangle?

Tags: python, opengl, pygame, pyopengl

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

vertices = ((1, 1, 1), (1, 1, -1), (1, -1, -1), (1, -1, 1),
             (-1, 1, 1), (-1, -1, -1), (-1, -1, 1), (-1, 1, -1))
edges = ((0, 4, 3), (6, 4, 3), (1, 3, 2), (5, 7, 2), (0, 4, 1), (7, 1, 4),
         (3,6, 2), (5, 1, 6), (0, 3, 1), (2, 3, 5), (6, 5, 4), (7, 2, 4))

def draw_cube(): 
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)
    for edge in edges:
        for index in edge:
            glVertex3fv(vertices[index])
    glEnd()

def main():
    pygame.init()
    display = (800, 600)
    pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF | OPENGL)
    gluPerspective(45, (display[0]/display[1]), 0.1, 50.0)
    glTranslatef(0, 0, -5)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        glRotatef(1, 3, 1, 1)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        draw_cube()
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(20)
        
main()
```

Output:

[image]

Desired Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an list of colors with one color for side of the cube:

```py
colors = [(1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1)]
```

Use [`glColor3fv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColor.xml) to set the color:

```py
def draw_cube(): 
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)
    for faceIndex, face in enumerate(faces):
        glColor3fv(colors[faceIndex // 2])
        for index in face:
            glVertex3fv(vertices[index])
    glEnd()
```

Enable the [Depth Test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test):

```py
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
```

See also [PyGame and OpenGL immediate mode](https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/blob/master/documentation/pygame_opengl/immediate_mode/pygame_opengl_immediate_mode.md#pygame-and-opengl-immediate-mode-legacy-opengl)

Note, there is also a problem with  your face indices. Minimal correct example:

[image]

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

vertices = [(-1,-1,-1), ( 1,-1,-1), ( 1, 1,-1), (-1, 1,-1), (-1,-1, 1), ( 1,-1, 1), ( 1, 1, 1), (-1, 1, 1)]
faces =    [(0,1,2), (0,2,3), (5,4,7), (5,7,6), (4,0,3), (4,3,7), 
            (1,5,6), (1,6,2), (4,5,1), (4,1,0), (3,2,6), (3,6,7)]
colors =   [(1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1)]


def draw_cube(): 
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)
    for faceIndex, face in enumerate(faces):
        glColor3fv(colors[faceIndex // 2])
        for index in face:
            glVertex3fv(vertices[index])
    glEnd()

def main():
    pygame.init()
    display = (300, 200)
    pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF | OPENGL)
    gluPerspective(45, (display[0]/display[1]), 0.1, 50.0)
    glTranslatef(0, 0, -5)
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        glRotatef(1, 3, 1, 1)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        draw_cube()
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(20)
        
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi so check out this link [Python Color Constants Module](https://www.webucator.com/article/python-color-constants-module)
then create a variable

```py
pinkcolor = (255,0,255)
```

or insert it wherever u build the triangle

and then lets say its a platform:

```py
pinkPlatform = pygame.draw.rect(screen,pinkcolor,
    pygame.Rect(pinkPlatformX, pinkPlatformY, pinkPlatformWidth, pinkPlatformHeight))
```

it should work i think

Comment: No, It do not work! You cannot use `pygame.draw.rect` with PyOpenGL.